# Como executar duas querys em uma declaração?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Eu preciso montar uma consulta MySQL que me retorne o total de linhas, e o total de linhas com valor maior que 1 na mesma consulta.

**Total de *linhas*:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabela
```

**Total de *linhas* com valor maior que 1:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tabela` WHERE `valor` < 1
```

Seria como juntar essas duas linhas em uma só, e me retornar o total de linhas e o total de linhas com valor maior que 1.

Comment: E por que tem esse requerimento?

Comment: Por que nao quero executar duas linhas de codigo, sendo que posso executar em uma só uai

Comment: E qual o ganho que você terá como isto?

Comment: Estamos a fugir do foco da pergunta

Comment: Pelo contrário, você está tentando fugir do foco da pergunta. Responder isto é relevante.

Comment: Perdão, nao é pra ser grosseiro, entretanto em algum lugar do SO diz que perguntas nao podem se basear em opinioes etc etc.. Mas se tanto insiste, eu pessoalmente prefiro executar em uma so linha tudo que eu preciso, por que ir duas vezes a padaria sendo que posso ir so uma e economizar meus pés?

Comment: user3163662 eu acredito que ele esteja especulando um melhor caminho para formular uma resposta boa para ti, *não é necessariamente uma questão de opinião*, porém a sua última frase faz sentido (ao menos para mim), talvez se o titulo fosse algo como "Como contar a quantidade de linhas em duas querys diferentes", mas mesmo assim é uma boa questão.

Comment: Seria bom dar uma revisava, nessa época ficou várias s/ aceitar.

Answer (score 4):

As duas seleções terão que ser feitas separadamente mas pode trazer o resultado de uma só vez combinando as duas seleções em uma terceira. O `select` pode retornar qualquer informação, mesmo que não dependa do banco de dados. Neste caso você receberá um resultado onde o "campo" `total` representará a primeira consulta e `totalMaior` representará a segunda.

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tabela`) AS total,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tabela` WHERE `valor` > 1) AS totalMaior;
```

Em PHP usaria algo assim:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tabela`) AS total,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tabela` WHERE `valor` > 1) AS totalMaior;");
$campos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo $campos["total"];
echo $campos["totalMaior"];
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/MultipleQuerys.php).

Answer (score 3):

Seria simples.

Experimente:

```
SELECT  
    ( SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM tabela
    ) AS TR,
    ( SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM tabela WHERE valor < 1
    ) AS TRCVM1
```

Isso retornará 2 resultados TR e o TRCVM1.

TR = `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabela`

TRCVM1 = `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabela WHERE valor < 1`

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer assim também:

```
select a.id,  b.id from (SELECT COUNT(*) as id from TABELA) a, (SELECT COUNT(*) as id from TABELA WHERE valor > 1) b
```

Answer (score 2):

Tem uma forma simples:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total_linhas,
       IF(valor < 1, COUNT(*), null) as total_maior_que_um
 FROM tabela
```